# change color in push execution of high chart column

Tags: javascript, json

this is how i am taking my series data..

```
$.getJSON('php/common/json/chartData/jsonSpeed.php?    Mobileplaca='+Mobileplaca+'&dtInicio='+dtInicio, function(JSONresult) {

yData = avgChart.series[0].data; //Array to store data for y column
xData = avgChart.xAxis.categories; //Array to store data for x column

xDataObj = JSONresult[0];
yDataObj = JSONresult[1];

for(var key in xDataObj){
xData.push(xDataObj[key]);
}
for(var key in yDataObj){
yData.push(yDataObj[key]);
//console.dir(data);
}
new Highcharts.Chart(avgChart);
});
```

i want to know how can i set the condition for my y series in push execution. for example if my yDatapush exceed from 40, it change the color of column in red..
can someone help me in this ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the color of data points manually:

Documentation: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tz8Ns/

```
data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, {y: 129.2, color: '#FF0000'}, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
```

so you could do something like

```
yData.push({y: yDataObj[key], color: yDataObj[key] > 40 ? '#FF0000' : '#000000'})
```

You may also be able to figure something out using threshold and negative color: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.threshold

Comment: yData.push({y: yDataObj[key], color: yDataObj[key] > 40 ? '#FF0000' : '#000000'})
yes this is what i am looking for.. Thanks it's works